# Access remote network with OpenVPN server

Tags: openvpn, ip, remote-access, public

I am currently trying to configure OpenVPN to access our company network remotely.

I have a question: when I configure the "client.ovpn" file, what should I put as Ip in this parameter: remote xx.xx.xx.xx 1194 ?

I can put the public address of the windows server but as soon as the server restarts the public address will change and everything will have to be redone.

How can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a question: when I configure the "client.ovpn" file, what should I put as Ip in this parameter: remote xx.xx.xx.xx 1194 ?

The IP address or [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) of the server.

> I can put the public address of the windows server but as soon as the server restarts the public address will change and everything will have to be redone.

First of all, it's easier to use DNS than IP's - so generally I would suggest using names. With a short TTL this will function reasonably well.

Second. Talk to your ISP. If you have a configuration where you require inbound traffic, you *should* have fixed IP. ISP's will handle this for you.